# React configureStore2.default.firestore is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I apologize for opening this post - I know there are others.  I've probably tried 20 different combinations of setup from other posts and I can't get past it. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

I am getting this error:

**configureStore2.default.firestore is not a function**

actions file:

```
import firebase from '../store/configureStore';
.....

export const setTweets = (tweets) => ({
    type: 'SET_TWEETS',
    tweets
  });

  export const startSetTweets = () => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
      const uid = getState().auth.uid;
      console.log("uid = ", uid);
     
      const postsRef = firebase
        .firestore()          //  <---- this line causes the error
        .collection("posts");
```

from configureStore

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth'
import 'firebase/firestore'
..........

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
  firebase.firestore().settings({ timestampsInSnapshots: true }) 

.......

 export { googleAuthProvider, firebase, store as default}
```

from package.json

```
 "firebase": "^8.1.1",

    "redux": "3.7.2",
    "redux-firestore": "0.14.0",
```

Comment: Use `import { firebase } from '../store/configureStore';` instead of `import firebase from '../store/configureStore';`

Comment: Argh, thanks @Dominik.  This one gets me vevery time.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be importing the default export from `configureStore` which is `store` but it looks like you want `firebase` instead.

If that's the case use `import { firebase } from '../store/configureStore';` in your actions file.

So your code would like this this:

```js
import { firebase } from '../store/configureStore';
// .....

export const setTweets = (tweets) => ({
    type: 'SET_TWEETS',
    tweets
  });

  export const startSetTweets = () => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
      const uid = getState().auth.uid;
      console.log("uid = ", uid);
     
      const postsRef = firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection("posts");
```

Read more about named exports here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export